# Very slow guards in my monadic random implementation (haskell)

Tags: performance, haskell, random, monads

I was tried to write one random number generator implementation, based on number class. I also add there Monad and MonadPlus instance.

What mean "MonadPlus" and why I add this instance? Because of I want to use guards like here:

```
--  test.hs       --

import RandomMonad
import Control.Monad
import System.Random 

x = Rand (randomR (1 ::Integer, 3)) ::Rand StdGen Integer

y = do
 a <-x
 guard (a /=2) 
 guard (a /=1)
 return a
```

here comes RandomMonad.hs file contents:

```
-- RandomMonad.hs --

module RandomMonad where
import Control.Monad
import System.Random 
import Data.List 
data RandomGen g => Rand g a = Rand (g ->(a,g))  | RandZero

instance (Show g, RandomGen g) => Monad (Rand g)
 where
 return x = Rand (\g ->(x,g))
 (RandZero)>>= _ = RandZero

 (Rand argTransformer)>>=(parametricRandom) =  Rand funTransformer 
  where 
  funTransformer g | isZero x = funTransformer g1
                   | otherwise = (getRandom x g1,getGen x g1)
   where
   x = parametricRandom val
   (val,g1) = argTransformer g
   isZero RandZero = True
   isZero _ = False

instance (Show g, RandomGen g) => MonadPlus (Rand g)
 where
 mzero = RandZero
 RandZero `mplus` x = x
 x `mplus` RandZero = x
 x `mplus` y = x 

getRandom :: RandomGen g => Rand g a ->g ->a
getRandom (Rand f) g = (fst (f g)) 
getGen :: RandomGen g => Rand g a ->g -> g
getGen (Rand f) g = snd (f g)
```

when I run ghci interpreter, and give following command

```
getRandom y (mkStdGen 2000000000)
```

I can see memory overflow on my computer (1G). It's not expected, and if I delete one guard, it works very fast. Why in this case it works too slow?

What I do wrong?

Comment: Irrelevant: the standard random number generator in Haskell *is* slow. Try System.Random.Mersenne instead.

Comment: Ok. But why so much memory is used, when I try it (System.Random) ? I think, problem in >>= definition. Is it tail recursive? I think it is.

Comment: I don't know (yet) — but you could use `guard (a /= 1 && a /= 2)`.

Comment: Of course. But I'm motivated for using guards exactly when I have many of them in my "do" statement.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of `(>>=)` is certainly wrong, but I cannot point to where because it is so complicated!  Instead I will explain why it cannot be defined correctly using an example.  Consider:

```
Rand (\g -> (42,g)) >>= const mzero
```

We need to get that `42` out, so we need a `g`.  The place to get the g is from the return value of the bind, so the answer is definitely:

```
Rand (\g -> ...)
```

For some `...`, responsible for returning a `(b,g)` pair.  Now that we have 42, we can evaluate `const mzero 42` and find that we have `RandZero`  But where are we going to get that `b`?  It is nowhere (in fact, *so* nowhere in this example that it can be any type whatsoever, since the type of the expression is `forall b. Rand b`).

What is the purpose of `RandZero` for your monad? Are you just trying to make `StateT g Maybe`?  My guess is that you are.  In that case, you might have more luck trying to implement *this* type:

```
newtype Rand g a = Rand (g -> Maybe (a, g))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your "monad" correctly, `(>>=)` fails to be associative.  Try defining

```
y' = do a <- do a' <- x
                guard (a' /= 2)
                return a'
        guard (a /= 1)
        return a
```

to check whether this is the case.  Effectively, your backtracking strategy can only undo the last step, not the entire computation.

Comment: I've realized that my strategy is wrong, and now I'm using liquid's strategy instead - it's ideal for my purpose.